# Behaviour of $L^2$ integrable smooth function at $\infty$

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

I have seen counterexamples of continuous functions $f$ such that they are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $|f(x)|\rightarrow \neq 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$. Now I was wondering what would happen if we have a smooth function . Will we have in this case that $|f(x)|\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you write "$\to\neq 0$" do you mean "does not converge to $0$" or "converges to a nonzero number"? The latter should be impossible for an $L^2$ function.

Comment: I mean does not converge to zero @Troposphere

Comment: No, smoothness won't change anything. Look at the counterexamples with continuous functions, they will most likely be already smooth or can be made so by "rounding" the spikes.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u$ be a fixed smooth [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) supported on $[0,1]$. Then you can consider
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when }x<0 \\ u(n^2(x-n)) & \text{when } n\le x<n+1 \end{cases} $$
This function is clearly smooth and $L^2$:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^1u^2(x)dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\int_0^1u^2(x)dx $$

However $f(x)$ has no limit as $x\to\infty$, since the value keeps oscillating between $0$ and $\max u$.

---

You can even find *analytic* examples, such as
$$ f(x) = e^{-(x^2\sin x)^2} $$
though it takes a bit more footwork to convince oneself that that is $L^2$.

Comment: Indeed. But/and as a sequel one can contemplate integrability conditions on derivatives (e.g., of an $L^2$ function) that have an impact on behavior at infinity.